# How to enable structural comparison of two source code files?

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I generated java class files using ant tool for a `.wsdl` file and after using clean up from Eclipse, I noticed some of the files had only moved code elements.

How to enable structure comparison in Beyond Compare? In other words, how to check/compare moved code element between two files?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare can't detect moved code elements and show them as a match. It will always show them as inserted and deleted code.

Comment: Any recommendations for the other tools?

Comment: I don't have a specific tool to recommend. The generic workaround for Beyond Compare is to use a source code formatter/beautifier on both files, then compare the formatted output.